# scanf function with MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I'm learning MPI and was fiddling with some of the besic functions, like `MPI_Bcast`. Usually one has the message in the main rank (i.e. 0) and broadcasts it to the others, so something like (this is a basic example from my notes)

```cpp
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // common buffer 'n' for every process
    int n, myid, numprocs, i;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

    // at first only process 0 has the value of n, e.g. n=5
    if(myid==0){
        printf("Enter n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    // broadcasted to every other process, now each of
    // has a separate n that can be independently modified
    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(myid==0){
        ++n; // 5->6 for proc 0
    }

    if(myid==1){
        n+=2; // 5->7 for proc 1
    }

    printf("n from process %d is %d\n", myid, n);
    /*
    upon execution (-np 4): 
    
    Enter n: 5
    n from process 0 is 6
    n from process 1 is 7
    n from process 2 is 5
    n from process 3 is 5
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Out of curiosity i tried to put the `scanf` out of the `if` clause, so to give every process an initial value for `n`:

```cpp
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int n, myid, numprocs, i;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(myid==0){
        ++n;
    }

    if(myid==1){
        n+=2;
    }

    printf("n from process %d is %d\n", myid, n);

    return 0;
}
```

When executing the code this is the result (`-np 3`):

`Enter n: Enter n: Enter n: 5`

`n from process 0 is 6`

Every process execute the `scanf` function but it seems that only the `0` prints the results. I wanted to ask why it happens, although i can figure that this is a misuse of the parallel input.

Comment: Please don't spam tags, C++ is not C. You also seem to be writing C++ as if it's C, both of which is indicative that you didn't learn C++ from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: Looks like the rest of the processes are still waiting for input...

Comment: Which MPI library are you using? Non root rank could/should read from /dev/null.

Comment: I'm using mpich 3.3.2